# Add Custom SObject to List of SObjects in Apex Controller

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I have a custom Apex controller where I have an SOQL query that gets a count of all objects that have a certain status and that are children of another object.  The query is:

```
List<SObject> statuses = [SELECT Status__c, COUNT(Id) statusCount FROM Application__c WHERE CERT__c = :certId GROUP BY Status__c];
```

Status__c is a Picklist.  I also have code to get all of the possible values of the Picklist.

What I want to do is if statuses does not contain any entries that have a specific Status__c value, to add the value name with a count of 0.  For some reason when I try to create a new SObject with a Status__c and Count, it doesn't seem to like it.  Is there a way to add a custom SObject to the list?  Or, should I be handling this differently?

Answer (score 0):

I was very surprised that your query works. Result of queries with `GROUP BY` is [`AggregateResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm), I didn't know it can be cast down to sObject. Maybe initial success with this made you fail in the next steps...

Something like this should point you in right direction:

```java
Map<String, Integer> results = new Map<String, Integer>();

for(Schema.PicklistEntry pe : Lead.LeadSource.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()){
    results.put(pe.getValue(), 0);
}
System.debug('Before: ' + JSON.serializePretty(results));

for(AggregateResult ar : [SELECT LeadSource, COUNT(Id) cnt FROM Lead WHERE LeadSource != null GROUP BY LeadSource]){
    results.put((String) ar.get('LeadSource'), (Integer) ar.get('cnt'));    
}
System.debug('After: ' + JSON.serializePretty(results));

Before: {
  "Some more types" : 0,
  "Hi Stackoverflow!" : 0,
  "Other" : 0,
  "Purchased List" : 0,
  "Partner Referral" : 0,
  "Phone Inquiry" : 0,
  "Web" : 0
}
After: {
  "Some more types" : 0,
  "Hi Stackoverflow!" : 0,
  "Other" : 0,
  "Purchased List" : 7,
  "Partner Referral" : 4,
  "Phone Inquiry" : 4,
  "Web" : 7
}
```